# Настройка JqueryUi slider pips

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Никак не получается добиться желаемого результата со slider-ом жуквэри.
Есть шаг в 5, хотелось бы получить labels в виде 1,5,10,15,20 и т.д
А в итоге есть 1,6,11,16,21 ..
Вариант с отсчетом с 0 не устраивает
Может кто сталкивался с данным вопросом? Заранее благодарен за любой совет.

`

```
$("#pips-slider")
    .slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 60,
        value: 10,
            step: 1 
    })

    .slider("pips", {
      rest: "label",
      step: 5
    });
```

`
https://jsfiddle.net/glad1uss/qwpcok7t/3/

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/374d4067ad7f0e79a8310307c27dbb6d.png - - скорее всего никак... оно тыкает на них через nth-child...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/a26e5wnm/ - такой костыль пришел в голову, но я не понял как получить текущее значение слайдера. Может вы знаете и уже доделаете. Сделать от 0 до 60, и просто запретить нулевое значение условием. Если сдвинуто туда - переделать значение в 1 (а возможно и ползунок сдвинуть куда надо)

Comment: Вы таки вдохновляете на создание костылей))
https://jsfiddle.net/glad1uss/k3Ltqsj5/24/